# Updating listview height to fill new form content (c#)

Tags: c#, xml, listview, height

I have a form with a border which contains a listview, within my c# code the height of the border is changed depending on a value. Right now the border height changes with no problem but how can I update the listview to have the same height as the border? Here is my xml:

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="PackageTemplate">
        <Border x:Name="PackageBorder" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" Margin="10" Padding="0" Width="100" >
            <Border.Style>
                <Style>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Status}" Value="1">
                            <Setter Property="Border.Background" Value="#FF999696"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Status}" Value="0">
                            <Setter Property="Border.Background" Value="#FFE4E4E4"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Layout}" Value="0">
                            <Setter Property="Border.Height" Value="100"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Layout}" Value="1">
                            <Setter Property="Border.Height" Value="200"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>                           
                </Style>
            </Border.Style>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="70"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <ListView  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Background="{x:Null}" x:Name="List" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Collection}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource ChipTemplate}" 
                          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="90" >
                    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                </ListView>

                <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding Path=Location}" FontSize="15" FontFamily="Arial" Foreground="Black" Background="{x:Null}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left"></Label>                  
            </Grid>
        </Border>            
    </DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `Xaml` you have set the ListView Height to 70 by setting `<RowDefinition Height="70"/>` and the Width to 90, the `ListView` will not get any bigger then that, you will need to set `<RowDefinition Height="70*"/>`  allow it to grow in height and remove the Width="90", or perhaps use `DockPanel`.

```
    <DockPanel>
        <Label DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Content="{Binding Path=Location}" FontSize="15" FontFamily="Arial" Foreground="Black"  />
        <ListView x:Name="List" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Collection}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource ChipTemplate}" 
                      ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="Black" >
            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        </ListView>
    </DockPanel>
```